# Complex row manipulation based on column value in SQL or Power Query

Tags: sql, plsql, powerbi, powerquery

I have a call dataset. Looks like this

[image]

If a call about a certain member comes in within 30 days of an "original call", that call is considered a callback. I need some logic or Power Query magic to handle this dataset using this logic. So the end result should look like this

[image]

Right now, I have the table left joined to itself which gives me every possible combination. I thought I could do something with that but it's proven difficult and when I have over 2 million unique case keys, the duplicates kill run time and overload memory. Any suggestions? I'd prefer to do the manipulation in Power Query editor but can do it in SQL. Plz and thank you.

Comment: what if 4/5 was on 3/29?

Comment: @horseyride Good question.  I think another way of putting it is whether there could be multiple call backs for the same initial call (i.e. if there are multiple calls within 30 days of the initial call).  I assumed only a single call back in my answer, and that the subsequent call would necessarily be a new call.

Comment: In addition to the above questions, please answer if you can have a call back on the same day as the initial call.

Comment: Ron will develop a great method once the details are settled, but honestly, PW is not going to work well on 2 million records. I think you are using the wrong tool.

Comment: no. The original call date is the ultimate starting point. Then, ANY call with the same member ID that comes within 30 days of the original call is considered callback. ANY call that comes in after 30 days of the original call should NOT be considered a callback to the original call. Therefore, if original call is 01/01 and calls with same member ID comes in on 02/05 and 02/12, the result would be 2 records, one with original call date of 01/01 and another with original call date of 02/05 and a callback date of 02/12

Comment: @Kdhosk You did not specifically address how you wanted displayed multiple call backs from the same original call. I have altered my algorithm to show separate records with the Call Date remaining the same, so long as the call back dates are within thirty days, as you can see in my 2nd example. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this in Power Query, but I have no idea how it will run with two million records.

It may be able to be sped up with judicious use of the `Table.Buffer` function. But give it a try as written first.

The code should be reasonably self-documenting

- Group by Member ID
- For each Member ID, create a table from a list of records which is created using the stated logic.
- expand the tables
- Mark the rows to be deleted by shifting up the Datediff column by one and applying appropriate logic to the Datediff and shifted columns.
- Code assumes that the dates for each Member ID are in ascending order. If not, an extra sorting step would need to be added

Try this M code. *(Change the Source line to be congruent with your own data source)*.

***Edit:***
*Code edited to allow for multiple call backs from an initial call*

```
let

//Change next line to be congruent with your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Case key", type text}, {"Member ID", Int64.Type}, {"Call Date", type date}}),

//Group by Member ID
//  then create tables with call back date using the stated logic
       #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Member ID"}, {
        {"Call Backs",(t)=>Table.FromRecords(
            List.Generate(
            ()=>[ck=t[Case key]{0}, cd=t[Call Date]{0}, cb = null, df=null, idx=0],
            each [idx] < Table.RowCount(t),
            each [ck=if Duration.Days(t[Call Date]{[idx]+1} - [cd]) < 30 
                        then [ck] else t[Case key]{[idx]+1},
                cd=if Duration.Days(t[Call Date]{[idx]+1} - [cd]) < 30 
                        then [cd] else t[Call Date]{[idx]+1},
                    cb = if Duration.Days(t[Call Date]{[idx]+1} - [cd]) < 30  
                            then t[Call Date]{[idx]+1} else null,
                    df = if Duration.Days(t[Call Date]{[idx]+1} - [cd]) < 30
                            then Duration.Days(t[Call Date]{[idx]+1} - [cd]) else null,
                    idx = [idx]+1],
            each Record.FromList({[ck],[cd],[cb],[df]},{"Case key","Call Date","Call Back Date", "Datediff"}))
        )}
        }),
    #"Expanded Call Backs" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Call Backs", 
        {"Case key", "Call Date", "Call Back Date", "Datediff"}, 
        {"Case key", "Call Date", "Call Back Date", "Datediff"}),

    #"Shifted Datediff" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Expanded Call Backs") & {
        List.RemoveFirstN(#"Expanded Call Backs"[Datediff]) & {null}},
            type table[Member ID=Int64.Type, Case key=text, Call Date=date, Call Back Date=date, Datediff=Int64.Type, shifted=Int64.Type ]),

    #"Filter" = Table.SelectRows(#"Shifted Datediff", each [shifted]=null or [Datediff]<>null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Filter,{"shifted"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***Example with multiple callbacks***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think you can do this with Lead function.

here is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f7cabdbe4d1193e5f0da6bd6a4571b96

```
select 
  a.*, 
  LEAD(CallDate, 1) OVER (
    Partition by memberId 
    ORDER BY 
      CallDate
  ) AS "CallbackDate", 
  LEAD(CallDate, 1) OVER (
    Partition by memberId 
    ORDER BY 
      CallDate
  ) - a.calldate AS DateDiff 
from 
  mytable a
```

Comment: I dont think it does. This generates a combination for 3/28 and 4/5, which are not paired

Comment: guess I don't understand,  a callback occurred on 3/28 for Id 3, then on 4/5 they called back again for id 3.

Comment: But that call on 4/5 is 30+ day from the original call date (3/2) so it's considered a new call, and needs to open a new record